# How to add different quantity packages for a product?

Tags: magento2, qty

I am using **Magento 2.2** and want to be able to set different packages that can be purchased. Like for wine for example. It should be possible to order 1 bottle or 6 or 18 for example.

I know the qty could be entered in the qty field, but I want to be able to add the different package sizes seperately. Please also take a look at https://screenshots.firefox.com/z3HG7swzqBObULdZ/null

Is there something already build in?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need to create Bundle Products. It will solve your purpose.

Comment: But will it show the + / - option for each bundled product?

Comment: yes, it will based on how you configure your bundle products.